# Null Object Reference when trying to consume Web Api Data In MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

To follow on from a previous post I have made, I am making a web ATM for a university project. For this, I have an MVC application through which most of the cunctionality is based, and an API project, which has a database inside it. I am trying to consume the data from this database and display them in my Index Method currently. However, when I run my solution, I am given a Null Object Reference at the following line of my Index View:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.ExcRateList)
```

I am struggling to figure out why this is not working, and am turning to you good people for a possible solution.

Below is my Index Get Method located in my controller:

```
   // GET: AtmAccounts
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModels.ExcClient ex = new ViewModels.ExcClient();
        ViewBag.listRates = ex.findAll();
        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ViewModels.AtmAccountVM atmVm = new ViewModels.AtmAccountVM();
        atmVm.AtmAccountList = db.AtmAccounts.Where(a => a.UserId == userID).ToList();
        atmVm.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        atmVm.ExcRateList = ViewBag.listRates;
        return View(atmVm);
 }
```

The parts of which that concern this problem are:

```
  ViewModels.ExcClient ex = new ViewModels.ExcClient();
        ViewBag.listRates = ex.findAll();
```

and

```
atmVm.ExcRateList = ViewBag.listRates;
```

The View Model AtmAccountVM controls the values passed between my different methods, including that of my API (Or at least, it should):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ATMApplication.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ATMApplication.ViewModels
{
public class AtmAccountVM
{
    public List<AtmAccount> AtmAccountList { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> TransactionsList { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    //These variables are used for the various ATM functions accessible to     customers
    public decimal DepositAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal WithdrawAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal TransferAmount { get; set; }
    public string AccTransfer { get; set; }


    // These are Used for the Restful Service
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public List<ExcRate> ExcRateList { get; set; }





    }
  }
```

Following are the view models ExcRate, which stores the data retrieved from the API, and ExcClient which fetches it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace ATMApplication.ViewModels
{
public class ExcRate
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set;}
}
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



namespace ATMApplication.ViewModels
{
public class ExcClient
{
    private string Base_Url = "http://localhost.57341/api/values";

    public IEnumerable<ExcRate> findAll()
    {


        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Base_Url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("rates").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var Rates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExcRate>>(responseData);
                return Rates;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And finally, here is the Index View the bottom part of which is meant to display this data in a table:

```
@using ATMApplication.ViewModels
@model ATMApplication.ViewModels.AtmAccountVM


<h2> Accounts Held for Customer: @Model.UserName </h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Account", "Create")
</p>
<style typw ="text/css">
span {
color: darkcyan;

}

</style>
<div style="background-color:lightyellow; color: black;">


<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AtmAccountList.First().AccountNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AtmAccountList.First().AccountBalance)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AtmAccountList.First().AccType.AccountType)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.AtmAccountList)
    {

        <tr>

            <td>
                <div style="background-color:lightyellow">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountNumber)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="background-color:lightyellow">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountBalance)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="background-color:lightyellow">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccType.AccountType)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="background-color:lightyellow">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Deposit", "Deposit", new { id = item.Id })
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:lightyellow">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Quick Withdraw", "Quick Withdraw", new { id = item.Id })
                </div>
                <div style="background-color: lightyellow">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Withdraw", "Withdraw", new { id = item.Id })
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:lightyellow">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Transfer", "Transfer", new { id = item.Id })
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:lightyellow">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Transactions", "Transactions", new { id = item.Id })
                    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@Model.AtmAccountList[0].Id" />
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<h2>Exchange Rates</h2>
<p>
These are the current exchange rates (in GBP):
</p>
<br/>
<div style="background-color:lightcyan">
<table class="table">
   <tr>

       <th>Currency Code</th>
       <th>Currency Name</th>
       <th>Exchange Rate (GBP)</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach (var item in Model.ExcRateList)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>@item.Code</td>
           <td>@item.Name</td>
           <td>@item.Rate</td>
       </tr>
   }
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like `ex.findAll()` returns `null`, You need to find out why.

Comment: Make sure that responseData can be cast to ExRate.

Comment: Do you have an endpoint which returns valid data when trying this url `http://localhost.57341/api/values/rates` ?

Comment: When you are stepping through the code what does `responseData` look like?  And `Rates` before it is returned?

Comment: It looks as though the responsedata and Rates aren't actually being touched at all. Stepping through the code, putting breakpoints at the points where responseData and Rates would have values assigned to them, and the code just doesn't break there at all. Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that the following line in the ExcClient class throws a null reference exception: 

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)

causing the if loop not to initiate. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: Still having problems with this :/